# What is "hybrid graphics card"?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, amd-graphics-card

I am considering buying laptop, capable for semi-professional graphics/3d works. Is ATI hybrid graphics card an advantage or not? What difference does it make?

Comment: [Wikipedia article on ATI Hybrid Graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_graphics).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hybrid graphics simply means that it switches between a lower powered integrated GPU(for lower power use and heat) and a more powerful discrete GPU (when performance is needed). Unlike some other approaches, crossfireX seems to allow for dissimilar cards to be used together, so in some situations both the IGP and discrete GPUs can be used at once.

Answer (score 0):

If it's what I think they mean, it's a graphics card that has its own onboard memory, e.g. 1GB, but if need be, it can share the system's memory also to increase the amount of memory it has available.

On mine it is 1GB as standard and can use up to 2GB of RAM.

If not, it could also be the switching type card where, when you are using it for gaming / 3D, it switches over to the higher power card, then when viewing web pages etc. it switches back over to a lower power version.